# Preview image shows its white screen?

Tags: xcode

I am try to open .png images in preview it shows white screen?

Can any one help me.

Thanks,
subbu

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer here. In case anyone else finds this question and needs a solution. Take Xcode out of full screen mode. Still not fixed in 5.2

[Xcode 5.0.1 don't show images when you select it in navigation area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617191/xcode-5-0-1-dont-show-images-when-you-select-it-in-navigation-area)

Answer (score 0):

1. may be you have changed the extension of image .jpg to .png  like this

2.May be source not available

Comment: Thanks arnold, But I am not changing any thing. I am try to open apple default images but its shows white screen.

Answer (score 0):

A: change your image extension to jpg
B: go to ib to your imageview and go to the attributes bar.
C: In image: rewrite your image.