# Xcode 5.0.1 don't show images when you select it in navigation area

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5, preview, xcode5.0.1

Before the last update to Xcode 5.0.1, when i press on any image in the navigation area, the image preview was shown at the Editor area, but since Xcode 5.0.1, a blank screen is shown as follow:

[image: Empty Preview screen]
how to get the preview back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try exit from full screen, it helped me :)

Comment: Its back without any action from me!!

Comment: I too have this issue. FreeGor's answer did make this image return when not in full screen mode but i always work in full screen mode If anyone knows of a full fix that would be great.

Comment: it is bug Xcode 5.0.1. I am sure that Apple is aware of it, waiting for the Xcode update.