# Cannot visualize images inside Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I cannot visualize images in Xcode 5. When I select them on the left panel they don't show, this used to working.

Is it some configuration from coming from Xcode 4 that I am missing?

I tried restarting and creating other project and does not seem to work for me, only code is seen, no images, tried png jpeg etc no do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19617191/xcode-5-0-1-dont-show-images-when-you-select-it-in-navigation-area), are you perhaps running Xcode on full-screen?

There's a known bug about images missing on Xcode 5:

https://devforums.apple.com/thread/211772?tstart=0

I just tried a new sample project with Xcode 5.1 Developer Preview and it looks like it is not fixed yet.

Comment: Thanks!! images fades when put full screen and show when go full screen, I hope they fix it