# png files not visible in xcode + cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, png, project-navigator

I am developing with cocos2d-iphone under Xcode. The problem seems to be a tool problem. Clicking on a file under the Project Navigator usually shows that file. If it is source code, you see the source text in the main pane. If it is an image file, if you click on the filename the image shows in the main pane.

At the moment, none of my images/png-files show up when I click on them. Yet they are clearly being loaded into the bundle and show up in the app when it is run.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Restart Xcode & Computer. If that doesn't help, check if opening & saving the PNG files fixes it, for instance with Seashore or maybe Preview.app. Some PNG files may be "optimized" and Xcode may not be able to show them, though that is speculative.

Comment: Tried all of the above with no luck. Weird.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot visualize images inside Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254692/cannot-visualize-images-inside-xcode)

Comment: Turns out this has already been answered. Known bug, images will not show when running Xcode in fullscreen mode.